# How to add/remove Multicast Group under a specific interface (Windows)

Tags: windows, multicast

I have a multicast camera on ip 225.1.2.3.

On my computer, I can play video in VLC over LAN card or Wi-Fi.
But when i start playing with ffplayer (ffplay.exe) it looks like it registers to multicast:
[image: image1]

and because of that multicast is added to a specific network adapter.
[image: image2]

but this is not shown in
[image: image3]

After this multicast IP address is added to specific network (on image added to Wi-Fi) I tried to play it on LAN card. Video can't be played anymore. 
I checked Wireshark and packets are coming to LAN device but video can't be played.

My question is how to remove joined multicast from a specific network adapter?

I tried

```
route delete 225.1.2.3
```

but since this IP is not shown in route print this doesn't work.

Also tried

```
route -p add <multicast address> MASK <subnet mask> <adapter primary address>
route -p add 225.1.2.3 MASK 255.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
```

but didn't help

To fix I disabled the Wi-Fi adapter, and the reference to multicast was lost. After that I was able to play video on LAN again. But this is not a good fix, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution, to add network device ip in to URL like @William John Holden said.

udp://@225.10.28.19:15004 --miface=169.100.27.103"

For me it worked

udp://@225.10.28.19:15004?localaddr=169.100.27.103"

Answer (score 2):

Multicast joins are very different from the unicast routes that you see in the `route` command. The `route` command shows unicast destinations that your computer can send to. The `show joins` subcommand of `netsh` indicates what multicast IP addresses your computer is listening to. Usually the software application chooses what interfaces (often all) to listen on. [In VLC](https://superuser.com/a/870842) you can specify the listening IP interface in the URL, such as `udp://192.0.2.15@239.255.0.15:65001` where `192.0.2.15` is the IP address on the interface you wish to receive packets sent to `239.255.0.15`. You may be able to keep VLC receiving multicast packets on the LAN by specifying the LAN IP address in the URL like this.

Comment: Didn't know that i can add interface ip in the URL, i will definitely try it.